# Parameters lost zeros in Ajax request

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, get, webmethod

I send parameters for `WebMethod` with `Ajax` and receive um object. But, paramters lost `zeros` in `WebMethod`, i send "00001234", in backend paramenters is "1234"

Ajax Code:

```
 var content = {valueS: "00001234" };
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: content,
            async: false,
            url: "myPage.aspx/GetData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) { OnSucess(data); },
            error:   function(data) { OnError(data); }
        });
```

Webmethod Code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
    public static string GetData(string valueS)
    {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
 var content = {valueS: "'00001234'" };
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: content,
            async: false,
            url: "myPage.aspx/GetData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) { OnSucess(data); },
            error:   function(data) { OnError(data); }
        });
```

seems `valueS` is being deserialized to a number first, in which case it will loose its leading zeros.
The request generated by your code looks like this `myPage.aspx/GetData?valueS=00001234`

while the one generated by my code looks like this `myPage.aspx/GetData?valueS=%2700001234%27`, hence will be correctly deserialized as a string.